# In the c# SemanticModel is there a way to tell a nullable value type from a reference type?

Tags: c#, refactoring, nullable

I am trying to write a custom c# 8 refactoring on classes that are using the new nullable syntax.

I tell the difference between between the "actual" types and the "nullable"
types by checking for the "?" at the end of the type name.

The problem is how do I know which variables need a ".Value" to get the value
and which variables dont?

For example:

```
#nullable enable

public class C 
{
   public int actualInt {get; set;}
   public int? nullableInt {get; set;}
   public string actualString {get; set;}
   public string? nullableString {get; set;}
}
```

Once I have the symantic model, I can get the symbol information like this:

```
IPropertySymbol symbolInfo = SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(property) as IPropertySymbol;
```

But for "actualInt", I see that it is has

symbolInfo.Type.Name == "Int32"  (good)

IsReferenceType == true (huh?)

IsValueType == false (huh?)

I would have expected to see IsValueType == true

Comment: Are you just doing so to determine if the type of a property is Nullable or not? and if so have you tried doing so using PropertyInfo?

Comment: @Tayyab:  I think that PropertyInfo is part of System.Reflection which can be used at run-time to see information about the property.  I need my information before running the application.  I am trying to create a refactoring that can look at the syntax tree and semantic model from the compilation, but it does not create instances of the class to reflect on.